# Finding the smallest field that contains two sets

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am asked to find the smallest field that contains the sets {$1$} and {$2,3$}, if $S=${$1,2,3,4$}.

I understand that with the field, I want to find the unions, intersections, complements, and then the empty set and S.

The answer is as follows:
$F=${{}, {$1$}, {$4$}, {$1,4$}, {$2,3$}, {$1,2,3$}, {$2,3,4$}, {$1,2,3,4$}}

My question is:
Where did the {$4$} element come from?  Is it from the Union of {$1,4$}?

Comment: You must be using the term "field" in a way I haven't yet heard, connected to set theory. Define this, please: what's for you "a field"?

Comment: I think the field here refers to $\sigma$-field.

Comment: @DonAntonio Since the OP put the tag `probability-theory` under the question, would it be clear that it means "field" in $\sigma$-field as "algebra" in $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Sorry, you are all correct.  I meant that it is a sigma field!

Answer (score 2):

It is the complement of $\{1\}\cup\{2,3\}$ in $S$.

Comment: Okay, so I am supposed to also take not only the complement of {1}, {2,3}, but also the complement of the Union of {1} and {2,3} when finding the sigma field?

Comment: By definition, yes. You might want to be careful: 'field' and $\sigma$-field are two different concepts in general.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate a field generated by a family of sets $\mathcal M$ containing $S$, you need to:

1) add the complements of the sets to $\mathcal M$

2) Take any two sets and add their intersection to $\mathcal M$ until all the intersections are in $\mathcal M$

2) Take any two sets and add their union to $\mathcal M$ until all the unions are in $\mathcal M$

In other words the field generated of $\mathcal M$ is:

$$(\mathcal M\cup\mathcal M^c)_{ds}$$

Where the elements of $\mathcal M^c$ are the complement of each set of $\mathcal M$, and $d$ and $s$ means the closure to finite intersection and finite union respectively.

If by field you understand $\sigma$-field, then it is more complicated than this, although for finite $S$ (which is your case), the field and $\sigma$-field concepts are identical.

Comment: This is an old answer but if $\mathcal{M}$ is nonempty, it's not neccesary to have $S \in \mathcal{M}$.