# Find the smallest $\sigma$-field

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

[image]

I have the definition of a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal A$: A collection of subsets of $\mathcal X$ that

1. $\mathcal X,\emptyset\in \mathcal A$
2. If $A\in \mathcal A$, then $A^c=\mathcal X-A\in\mathcal A$
3. If $A_1,A_2,\dots\in\mathcal A$, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in\mathcal A$

So if the $\sigma$-field is to contain $\{1\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$, it must contain their complements, $\{2,3,4\}$ and $\{4\}$. It must also contain any finite or infinite union so $\{1,4\}$ and its complement, $\{2,3\}$. Lastly it must contain the entire set and the null set $\{1,2,3,4\},\emptyset$.

Have I missed anything? Fairly sure I haven't this time.

This is a very [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103841/finding-the-smallest-field-that-contains-two-sets).

Comment: Correct. The more common term for $\sigma$-field is $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Cheers and ty. $\color{white}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I measure theory it is  $\sigma-$algebra but in Probability Theory it is $\sigma-$field.